# Get number of dates as selected in Windows Forms MonthCalendar for Powershell

Tags: forms, events, powershell, calendar

I am using Powershell to create a GUI calendar and I need to be able assign a variable to the number of dates selected as the user selects them. I imagine I would have to use an event but am not sure how to procede. Basically, if a user selects a range of more than 10 days I need a checkbox on the same form to be checked. I am doing something similar with a listbox but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same with the calendar. Thanks.

Listbox code:

```
$Listbox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$Listbox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,80) 
$Listbox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,210) 
$Listbox2.Height = 210
$Listbox2.SelectionMode = "MultiExtended"
$Listbox2Content | ForEach-Object {[void] $Listbox2.Items.Add($_)}
$Listbox2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",11,0,3,1)
$Listbox2.Add_SelectedValueChanged({
    If (($Listbox2.SelectedItems).Count -ge 10) {$Checkbox2.Checked = $True}
    If (($Listbox2.SelectedItems).Count -lt 10) {$Checkbox2.Checked = $False}
    })
```

Calendar Code:

```
$Calendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
$Calendar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(12,80)
$Calendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$Calendar.ShowToday = $True
$Calendar.MaxDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
$Calendar.MinDate = $OldestLog
$Calendar.MaxSelectionCount = "$CalendarDateRange"
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($Calendar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$data_selected` scriptblock prints the number of selected dates. I attached it to the `DataSelected` event so it fires when you click on a date or make a range selection.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$date_selected = {
    write-host (($_.End - $_.Start).Days + 1)
}

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form   
$form.text = "Calendar"
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(190,190) 

$cal = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar   
$cal.add_DateSelected($date_selected)

$form.Controls.Add($cal)
$form.Add_Shown($form.Activate())  
$form.showdialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Perfect. I simply replaced the write-host with a variable in the script scope and it works great. Thanks so much.